# In C++, what does this mean: "using ClassName<arg1, arg2>::functionName;"

Tags: c++

What does the "using" below do? I thought using is meant to perform a type alias, but there's no "=" sign after using, what is it aliasing on?

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
class MyClass{

  public:
     using AnotherClass<A,B,C>::functionName;

   //
}
```

Comment: _"...Introduces a name that is defined elsewhere into the declarative region where this using-declaration appears...."_ [Using-declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) see the examples

Comment: It's useful when you want to add a function to MyClass with the same name and different parameters but still have access to the base class version.  Without the `using`, the function in MyClass would hide the base class version.  Have a look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/QOQNjleND  The MyClass version works with the `using` and ThirdClass doesn't because the local function hides the base class version.

Comment: If `functionName` is a function name and not an enumerator, `MyClass` should inherit from `AnotherClass<A,B,C>` somehow. Are sure the code you presented is correct?

Comment: `using` is one of those C++ keywords that has several different purposes and meanings.